# Theming Drupal 7's Ubercart "/cart" page

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I'm trying to theme Drupal 7's Ubercart 3 `/cart` page, but I'm struggling to find the theming function to do so.

I believe the right code may be located in `template.tpl.php`, but I am not sure.

Where in Drupal is the code to theme this page?

Answer (score 3):

Create a new template file and name it `page--cart.tpl.php`

For more information about Drupal theming suggestions: http://drupal.org/node/1089656

(Don't forget to clear the cache after adding the new template file)

**Another way** to use [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module with [theme developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module to get all available theme suggestions.

**Update:**

If you are looking to style just the cart section, why don't use CSS. In Ubercart, the cart section has an div id `div#cart-form-pane`

Comment: Using CSS would be an option, although I need to alter the structure of the data slightly and the data being in a table restricts what I'd like to achieve.

Comment: To change the structure of the form, you should create a `hook_form_alter` and use `uc_cart_view_form` as the form ID. Template suggestions will not help you in this case.

Comment: So there is no easier way to theme it like how the Cart Block was? (Just editing the `theme_uc_cart_block_items` function)

Comment: I think so, Unfortunately.

Comment: Thats a shame... oh well! Thanks for your help! :D

Comment: PapaSmurf, did you ever find a solution for this? If so, can you please share?