# How to theme shopping cart in ubercart

Tags: drupal-7, ubercart

I use drupal 7 and ubercart 3. How can I theme cart page. I used to create page--cart.tpl.php but I don't know how to get item of cart to theme it

Comment: This question already exists. See [Theming Drupal 7s Ubercart “/cart” page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856979/theming-drupal-7s-ubercart-cart-page)

Comment: I read that topic. But I don't know how to get all items in cart to show in page--cart.tpl.php. Do you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shopping cart at /cart is a form that you can theme override. In the template.php file, add the following function.

```
function yourtheme_uc_cart_view_form(&$variables) {
  //$form contains the UC cart form object
  $form = &$variables['form'];

  //$form['items'] will contain a table object with the cart items
  $output = '<p>some test output.</p>';
  $output .= drupal_render_children($form);
  return $output
}
```

Comment: If I use page--cart.tpl.php how can I get $form to theme?